# jquery make text div scroll

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a div containing text scroll up.

I've searched tutorials and have this at the moment (its not working)

```
$( "#div" ).animate({ up: 100 }, { duration: 1000, step: 1 });
```

What am I doing wrong?

### update

Sorry for the confusion, I meant I wanted the whole text to pan / scroll / rise up the page, not scroll to a close with the scrollUp function.

Comment: this is unclear.  The first answer was the correct answer to your question, then you added more details in a comment on that answer.  Show us what you have.  This code doesn't do anything, and scrolling up is different from sliding up the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the div to disappear, try

```
$('#div').slideUp('slow');
```

You can read about options of this function here: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

not sure why i got a -1 for answering the question. after reading your edit you can try something like this

```
var newTop=(0 - $('#div').height());
$('#div').animate({
         top: newTop+'px',
         opacity : 0
 }, 1000);
```

this should also work

```
var newTop=($('#div').offset().top+ $('#div').height());
$('#div').animate({
     top: '-=' +newTop+'px',
     opacity : 0
 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle with animate..  Up isn't a valid animate argument.  This particular example uses `left`.  You could also use `top`.

http://jsfiddle.net/AueNk/

Answer (score 0):

Are you #div is the id of the current div ?

```
$('div').slideUp();
$('div').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the parameters you pass to the animate should be the CSS values that you expect the animation to be when the animation is finished.

Try this code:

```
$('#test').animate(
{
    top: '0'
}, 1000
);
```

You can set the position of the element to relative:

```
<div id="test" style='position: relative; top: 100px;'>test test test </div>
```

[Js fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/CqsDy/1/)